# In java, how to make a single thread to wait for a process to finish?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, wait

Here is what I have:
I have a thread that starts a process, this process is created by ProcessBuilder and starts a string command in terminal. There are many concurrent threads that do the same, but on different data.

Here is what I want to do:
I want to make a single thread (which started a process) to wait for that process until it finishes. I came up with two methods, and none is working.

method 1: to use process.waitFor(); and this causes all concurrent threads to wait for one single process (usually the first one) to finish. The description of waitFor(); says that it makes a single thread to wait, but that's not what it does, it actually makes ALL threads to wait. Hence the program is not concurrent anymore.

method 2: to run another thread that reads the piped stream out of that process, waits until there is stream, and then, runs the function that was supposed to run after that process. The drawback is that there are many threads right now so I prefer not to use this method. The other issue with this method is that I get confused that which of these properties of the process should I use? OutputStream, InputStream or ErrorStream?

Here is the code:

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread{
private String[] incommand;    //this is the command for the process builder
private String newoutputfile;
InputStream ins = null;
Reader r = null;
BufferedReader br = null;
ProcessBuilder pbtx = null;

public Thread1(String[] incommand, String newoutputfile){
    super("Thread1");
    this.incommand = incommand;        
    this.newoutputfile = newoutputfile;
    this.pbtx = new ProcessBuilder();
}
@Override
public void run(){
    try{                    
                pbtx.command(incommand);                                     
                Process ptx = pbtx.start();
                //to make sure job is done
                ptx.waitFor(); //problem is apparently here
                // made sure job is done
                //the next function is supposed to run after the process is finished                
                    rite();                    
                //
            } catch (IOException ex){
                System.out.println("exception in thread t1");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException yo){
            System.out.println("exception in thread t1");
            }
            }
```

By the way, the process is a ffmpeg process, each process works on different video data (no data dependencies or race condition or what so ever here). All these thread1 threads are made and started by another main thread in another function (main). The operating system in Linux. The IDE is Netbeans (that's where I get the description of each function). I tried to keep the copy-pasted code as short as possible (for simplicity), so if you think that the code for other functions or the rest of the program is needed please inform me to paste them here.

Thank you very much,

Comment: How are you starting your thread? I seriously doubt that Process.waitFor() freezes all the threads.

Comment: Thak you for your answer. The threads are started by threadobject.start() and then threadobject.join() in the main program. Not using .join() will cause the threads to race over their input variables.

Comment: Well, using `.join()` will cause the threads to wait. `Process.waitFor()` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do need to use the separate thread to read the input; I didn't find a way to avoid it. I use the following algorithm ([in the H2 database](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/tools/org/h2/build/BuildBase.java#331)), and it works fine for me. Please also note the `redirectErrorStream`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command(cmd.array());
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
copyInThread(p.getInputStream(), quiet ? null : sysOut);
p.waitFor();
return p.exitValue();

private static void copyInThread(final InputStream in, final OutputStream out) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    int x = in.read();
                    if (x < 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.write(x);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    } .start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With a little bit of modifiation of this code, my program is working now. The only drawback here is there are too many threads created right now.

Comment: Oh, and BTW I had to remove that p.waitFor(); again because it causes the old problem, halting all threads and processes except the one who is waiting.

Comment: I think p.waitFor() is not really needed in this case, but strange is that I use it and never saw any problem with it...

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 with Process.waitFor() should work. I think you are starting Thread1 wrong.

Here is a simple example. You can copy it and try it. `StackOverflowPinger` starts a new ping process.

```
public class StackOverflowPinger implements Runnable{

    public StackOverflowPinger(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    private int id;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pbuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
            Process pingprocess = pbuilder.command("ping", "www.stackoverflow.com").start();        
            int pingresult = pingprocess.waitFor();
            if(pingresult == 0)
                System.out.println("Pinger Nr." + this.id + " successfully pinged stackoverflow.");
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

The `Sleeper` sleeps for 250 milliseconds.

```
public class Sleeper implements Runnable{

    public Sleeper(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    private int id;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(250);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Sleeper " + this.id + " finished sleeping.");
    }
}
```

And here is the Main that instantiates and starts the threads.

```
public class ProcessMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i<4; i++){
            new Thread(new StackOverflowPinger(i)).run();
            new Thread(new Sleeper(i)).run();
        }
    }
}
```

Since the ping process takes much longer than 250 milliseconds the expected output should be something like this.

```
Sleeper 3 finished sleeping.
Sleeper 0 finished sleeping.
Sleeper 1 finished sleeping.
Sleeper 2 finished sleeping.
Pinger Nr.0 successfully pinged stackoverflow.
Pinger Nr.1 successfully pinged stackoverflow.
Pinger Nr.3 successfully pinged stackoverflow.
Pinger Nr.2 successfully pinged stackoverflow.
```

But the real output is like this.

```
Pinger Nr.0 successfully pinged stackoverflow.
Sleeper 0 finished sleeping.
Pinger Nr.1 successfully pinged stackoverflow.
Sleeper 1 finished sleeping.
Pinger Nr.2 successfully pinged stackoverflow.
Sleeper 2 finished sleeping.
Pinger Nr.3 successfully pinged stackoverflow.
Sleeper 3 finished sleeping.
```

Only if i change the lines

```
new Thread(new StackOverflowPinger(i)).run();
new Thread(new Sleeper(i)).run();
```

to

```
new Thread(new StackOverflowPinger(i)).start();
new Thread(new Sleeper(i)).start();
```

i get the expected output. So i think you are using your threads wrong.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your detailed answer. I, however, start the threads in a similar way. Except that after .start() I have to .join() the threads to prevent any race condition over their input variables. The problem still persists.